# how to reach eaves and facia board

Tags: paint

I want to paint exterior of house myself but not comfortable on 20' ext ladder. Anybody have scaffold recommendation or experience with renting it? Can it be taken down and moved rather easy? Does it take up a lot of space to store?

Comment: Have you ever used a ladder stabilizer that attaches to the top of the ladder?  It makes a huge difference.  I don't like ladders either, but a stabilizer made me comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

The modern method tends to be a manlift, which are available for rental. I was raised on using staging, but both speed and worker safety (if you stay away from powerlines and otherwise operate according to instructions) are enhanced with a manlift, which is why you see a lot more of them and a lot less staging on most construction projects these days.